# Firefox doesn't style :empty elements

Tags: css, firefox, contenteditable

Here is a snippet with a sample code:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 3px 6px;
}

[contenteditable]:empty:not(:focus)::before {
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
  color: gray;
  font-size: .9rem;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Firstname"></td>
      <td contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Lastname"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In Chrome and Safari, it works pretty much as expected:

[image]

For some reason, **in Firefox**, the `contenteditable` tds don't get the placeholder:

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

---

EDIT: It seems this is issue is more related to `:empty` than `[contenteditable]` as this code *kinda* works:

```css
[contenteditable]:not(:focus)::before {
    content: attr(data-placeholder);
    color: gray;
    font-size: .9rem;
}
```

But then the placeholder is always shown, hence not being an actual "placeholder" anymore.

Comment: I think it is a known bug in Firefox, when it is applied in a `table` or 'table's element
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1426869

Comment: It's shown because it's not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DreamTeK mentioned, Firefox seems to add a `<br>` in *empty* `contenteditable` elements.
His answer, using `input` instead of `contenteditable` **is valid**.

In case you have no choice but to use `contenteditable`, here is a *fix* in JS to remove this *unwanted* `br`:

```js
// VanillaJS
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('[contenteditable]').forEach((elt) => {
        if (elt.children.length === 1 && elt.firstChild.tagName === "BR") {
            elt.firstChild.remove();
        }
    })
});

// jQuery
/*
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('[contenteditable]').each((_, elt) => {
        if ($(elt).children().length === 1 && $(elt).has('br')) {
            $(elt).html('');
        }
    });
});
*/
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 3px 6px;
}

[contenteditable]:empty:not(:focus)::before {
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
  color: gray;
  font-size: .9rem;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Firstname"></td>
      <td contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Lastname"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firefox has incompatibility with `td:empty` not because there is an issue with the css engine but because the way Firefox handles `contenteditable` is by adding a `br` tag into the region.

[image]

An alternate way to do this would be to change the html to use `inputs` that you `disable` when content is present.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 0;
}

table input {
  border: none;
}

[placeholder] {
  color: gray;
  font-size: .9rem;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Forename</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input placeholder="Forename"></td>
      <td><input placeholder="Surname"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input placeholder="Forename" value="John" disabled></td>
      <td><input placeholder="Forename" value="Doe" disabled></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: In your code, if I type something in my td, as soon as unfocus the td, the placeholder shows next to the typed content ; this is most likely an issue with the fact I'm placing the placeholder in `::before`

Comment: @pistou So it does. Let's see if we can find a solution.